# Server Programming - Simple Multiplayer Game - Which protocol and technologies?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a year's experience writing client code but none with server stuff. I want to restrain the question a bit so I'll simplify what I'm trying to achieve.

I want to write server code such that two clients (Browser or iPhone / Android) can connect, when two player have connected they see a timer count down to zero. The clock would be synchronize on the server and the clients would be uniquely identifiable.

The trouble here is with the word connect, what do people use for multiplayer games? Open a TCP socket for two way communications? You can tell I'm not really sure what I'm talking about. I was hoping to use AppEngine but I'm not sure if it's suitable as it's request based.

I have some experience with Java and although Erlang sounds like the best choice this is something I just want to play with and push out fast so Java would be easier. I just need to know the best way to connect players etc.

Thanks,

Gav

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest we regard desktop and mobile systems as equal clients. What options are then?

- You write a socket server which will accept connections from clients. But then you need to write some socket client as well, even 2x - for a desktop and for a mobile OS. And the user will have to install this client.
- You launch a web server (whatever technology you like). It will expose some web services which will be equally accessible to both desktop and clients OSes. But still you need to write a client application (again 2x).
- You run a web server and make all functionality accessible via standard HTTP protocol. This way you won't even need a client - almost every desktop or a mobile OS has at least some web browser installed. JavaScript will provide for dynamic updates of your ticker.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer to a vague question - Socket programming is the most applicable to what I want to achieve it turns out, your answer gave me the keywords to do more research.

Comment: Javascript in this case could and should be considered as a client like the others.

Answer (score 6):

There is a good series of articles about [Networking for game programmers](http://gafferongames.com/networking-for-game-programmers/) by someone who does that stuff for a living.

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert on network communication, but if you don't mind loosing a few packets (or error checking in software) and you want fast, lean communication you could use [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol).  I think most time-sensitive data programs and streaming media use this protocol to avoid delays and keep packet size down.

Answer (score 1):

I realized a Client/ Server app a few years ago with java and ServerSocket (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html). You also have a SSL version.

So you create a ServerSocket and wait for connexion. When a client is connected, you create a thread that will discuss with this client with a protocol that you made.

http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/1356891/A-PatternFramework-for-ClientServer-Programming-in-Java.htm

If found this little framework :

http://www.bablokb.de/jcs/jcs.html

One of the hardest thing is to create your protocol , a good way to learn how to create one would be to understand how work the FTP (or HTTP ...).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that the J2EE model breaks down with near-realtime or multi-player demands. You migth want to consider the RedDwarf game server project.  It does for games what Servlets do for busienss logic and is open source.

http://www.reddwarfserver.org

> I suggest we regard desktop and mobile
>   systems as equal clients. What options
>   are then?

RedDwarf has a pluggable trabsport layer and can support any sort of client you wish.

Web servers are great for web type apps.  if your game acts like a web page-- is not multi-user, is turn based, and evolves very slowly-- then a web server is a fine chocie.

If it doesn't however, you need something a bit beefier  in technology.

Oh, and for what its worth, whetevr you do, if you want to write a server from scratch then DON'T use"ServerSocket."  That requries a thread per connection and will never scale.  Use NIO or use an NIO framewoprk like Netty.

Comment: Link is dead, here is the github link: https://github.com/reddwarf-nextgen/reddwarf